# Ninject - Creating a Custom NinjectWebServiceHost

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, ninject

I have a couple web services in my WCF project that require a custom `ServiceAuthorizationManager` to be able to authenticate OAuth calls. To do this, I created a custom `WebServiceHostFactory`. I am in the process of wiring up Ninject and am having a difficult time getting this converted over to a `NinjectWebServiceHostFactory`. Here is my code:

```
public class MyServiceHostFactory : WebServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return new MyServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }
}

public class MyServiceHost: WebServiceHost
{
    public MyServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {
        Authorization.ServiceAuthorizationManager = new OAuthAuthorizationManager();
    }
}
```

When I switch the `WebServiceHost` to a `NinjectWebServiceHost` it asks for an `IServiceBehavior` implementation. I have a `ServiceBehavior` attribute on my web service and I have a `ServiceBehavior` section in my `web.config`.

Has anyone seen this and been able to successfully implement something like this? Is there a better route to wire this up for my 2 web services? I do not want this to affect all of my web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just did this the other day. We found it easier to implement a new type of NinjectWebServiceHostFactory that wired up the custom AuthorizationManager for us.

```
public class OAuthHostFactory : NinjectWebServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        var host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        host.Authorization.ServiceAuthorizationManager = new OAuthAuthorizationManager();
        return host;
    }
}
```

This gives us the flexibility to pick and choose which routes or svc's we want to implement this particular factory on.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you'll have to create a custom attribute which implements the [`IServiceBehavior` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.aspx) yourself.

You're [`ApplyDispatchBehavior` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.applydispatchbehavior.aspx) implementation will want to look something like this:

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, 
    ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{
    Type serviceType = serviceDescription.ServiceType;
    IInstanceProvider instanceProvider = new NinjectInstanceProvider(
        new StandardKernel(), serviceType);

    foreach(ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
    {
        foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher in dispatcher.Endpoints)
        {
            DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime = endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime;
            dispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = instanceProvider;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, you're creating a custom [`IInstanceProvider` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx) implementation which depends on Ninject to create instances for the [`DispatchRuntime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.dispatchruntime.aspx).

[Peter De Rycke](http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/) goes into it further in his [blog entry "Using an IoC container to create WCF service instances"](http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/using-an-ioc-container-to-create-wcf-service-instances/) (note the code above was taken from there).

I imagine if you still want to use a `NinjectWebServiceHost`, you could pass an `IServiceBehavior` implementation much like the one Peter outlines above.